# How to move uploaded image freely in editor?

Tags: wysiwyg, summernote, froala

Currently I am using Summer-note editor. After uploading image, I'd like to let the users to move the image freely in the editor.

Is there any plug-in or source code for moving the uploaded image in editor?

Answer (score 0):

Allowing images to move freely means that absolute positioning should be used and that is not really great for web layouts. I work at [Froala Editor](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor) and we allow moving images through the editable area, but they are never positioned with absolute coordinates.